# gnome-shell gradually blurs everything in all windows and even the tray, how to fix?

Tags: icons, fonts, gnome-shell

It began 3 days ago, I am not sure what I could have changed.

I ran `metacity --replace` and everything looks correct (but I lose the top tray bar).
As soon I run `gnome-shell --replace` the horrible gradually blurring everything everywhere begins... It seems to start after 00:00h (when "NightLight" is automatically resumed), not fully sure yet.

The problem vanishes for a second as soon I move the mouse over the blurred window (or text box) or more granted if I click on it, or make the window refresh in any way.

I took a screenshot of a text, so it became an image, and I saw the image (of that text) becoming gradually blurred. So it is not a font problem.

It seems impossible to make a blurred screenshot (it seems to refresh before taking it, and after refreshing there is no blurring), I will take a photo.

---

ok, there is a terminal window on the left, and the right is this text question

the problem (doesnt seem to affect blue text on the terminal, couldnt be more weird this...), all the white text gets so blurry that becomes commpletelly unreadable on the terminal
[image]

ok image using metacity
[image]

ahh... the problem is so annoying, it fastly blurs everything, should I create a video to demonstrate? I dont know if I can upload here tho.

Does gnome-shell uses open-gl? It could be an open-gl video card hardware problem?

Comment: can be related to FXAA nvidia: https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/59c5a0/blurry_textvideoeverything_on_ubuntu_1604_with/, was enabled here too, just disabled it all (not only fxaa but enhance application and override anisotropy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled nvidia's FXAA (using nvidia settings app) based on this tip:
https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/59c5a0/blurry_textvideoeverything_on_ubuntu_1604_with/
Disabled also "enhance application settings" and "override anisotropy" (just to be sure).
Til now gnome-shell is working fine again (so apparently it is a 3D desktop) :)

Comment: just disable nvidia's FXAA and then 'alt+f2' and 'r' fixes gnome shell!